# Using Div to hide body until loaded, but can't click through div

Tags: jquery, html, preloader

I am using a preloader that animates before my page loads. Once the page loads, the div #loadfirst shows everything on the page.

Here's the mockup:

```
<style>
    #loadfirst {
        display: none;
        z-index: -1;
        pointer-events: none;
        position: relative;
    }
</style>


<div id="loadfirst">
  //my whole page
</div>
```

And yet when I try to click buttons and all, nothing works.

Here's a link to the page so you can see yourself if you'd like:

http://lavancier.com/research-data.php?ticker=AAPL&interval=2000&period=21

Thanks!

Comment: I solved it! I added pointer-events:none; to the body, and not to the loading div.

Comment: please add this as an answer and then mark as correct.